# How to calculate network jitter in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, jitter

I have a situation where I need to calculate the network jitter between the two computer connected over the internet from an ASP.NET application.

I have searched but I have not found any solution for this. Has any one done this before in c#.

I need a web page which the client computers can call. The web page should calculate the network statistics between the client and the server and save then in the database.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Please define "network jitter" in this context.

Comment: Also, web-applications are not sensitive to latency, so why is this an issue? What is the backstory?

Comment: by jitter I mean Packet delay variation - ‎Jitter

Comment: Again, why is this an issue? What are you doing this for?

Comment: The backstory is that, I need a web page which the client computers can call. The web page should calculate the network statistics and save then in the database.

Comment: I suppose you could use the `WebSockets` API in HTML5, but I don't think it's low-level enough to give usable figures (as the browser marshals data and can encapsulate the connection too)